# NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse - Apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment

I'm trying to run a simple REST-based app from eclipse juno (jetty web-server) (to be deployed later on google app engine)

Here's my code:

```
package co.suhas.live;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AppServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
            "http://www.google.com/search?q=google");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    resp.getWriter().println(response.toString());
    }
}
```

I have added **Apache HTTP Client** jar files to the BUILD PATH.

Including:

```
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar
httpclient-4.2.3.jar
httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar
httpcore-4.2.2.jar
httpmime-4.2.3.jar
```

But I get this error when I run it on `localhost`:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /app. Reason:

org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting this project from eclipse. Deleting the `.metadata` folder in `workspace` and importing the project back again after restarting eclipse. I don't know what could've been the issue.

Comment: Classic Java. I have a similar issue with IntelliJ. The code broke. I reverted to the version I know worked when I checked it in. Same issue. Gotta love Java.

Answer (score 5):

From an Eclipse Plug-in point of view. I encountered the same problem and solved it with the following steps:

1. Add lib folder to the root.
2. Add the jar files
3. Open the MANIFEST.MF file, go to Runtime tab
4. Add the items to the classpath
5. Go to the Build tab
6. Add the files to the output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a project that runs on a web-server you need your libraries to be deployed on this server. You can try the eclipse Deployment Assembly to do this for you.

Comment: I did this! I added it to the PATH of the Server using Eclipse's Quick Fix. But still no use.

Comment: add it in the deployment assembly to the web-inf/lib directory.

Comment: Eclipse auto-added it into **WEB-INF/lib** with Quick fix. So. :(

Answer (score 1):

For Intelli-J 12 Users:

1) Remove the library from Project Structure->Libraries.[image]

2) Re-add the project from the Maven repositories (where you are in Project Structure, click "+" and choose "From Maven..."). In the dialog that appears next, type "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk" and start the search. When the search is complete, choose the desired version [image]

3) Follow the usual prompts to "Fix" broken stuff that IJ12 alerts you about. You may be prompted to reload the project.

That fixed it for me. Thanks to @user2032663 and @orberkov for pointing to the fact that it's an IDE issue.

NOTE !!! : I am using OpenDNS and the Maven client in IntelliJ12 could not locate any libs > 1.4.1, I switched over to using Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) and retried, then it located the version I am using which is 1.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

When I experienced this issue, it turned out that when I added the Fluent API as a Maven dependency, it imported a different version of the HTTPClient API than the one I was already using. Both versions of the API were packaged in the resulting JAR's lib folder. The version conflict is what caused this error.

Adding entries to your classpath will fix the problem, because you're just manually specifying what version to use. However, to fix the underlying problem, I just needed to delete my target folder before rebuilding (or run maven clean). This removed any "cached" library JARs, and on the next build, only re-downloaded the correct one.

Hope that helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the generated war file. You can do this with a zip explorer like 7zip. Look to see which jar files are packaged into  /lib of the war file and make sure that `httpclient-4.2.3.jar` is included. If it is missing, you can take the suggestion made my SatelliteSD.

Comment: Just did this. `httpclient-4.2.3.jar` IS included in /lib

Comment: Maybe Jetty is not looking through that war file as I would expect it to. Maybe it is doing an "in place deployment" to make things "easier" for you.  I wound take the IDE out of the equation and just deploy the war file yourself. I have had some issues with Jetty, so I recommend you try another web server your are familiar with, like Tomcat or Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GWT, be careful, because gwt-dev.jar contains multiple apache projects, so your program may compile and run in development, but since gwt-dev.jar isn't deployed, you need to deploy the required jars.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .classpath file of your project against the one in your version control. Eclipse is good at loosing the bits pertaining to plugins, when you make changes to your project dependencies/classpath through the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

As you can see in the error (and as mentioned above), you're missing jar/s - and more specifically - you're missing a **http-client** jar.

Now you're opt to either find this jar manually and add it to your classpath/server's lib, or use a jetty's existing jar; I prefer the latter.

Running the following command in ***jetty.home*** will display all the jars loaded at runtime by the Jetty server:

```
C:\jetty-distribution-9.4.0.v20161208>java -jar start.jar --list-classpath
```

The output looks like this:

```
Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 34 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:                    (dir) | ${jetty.base}\resources
 1:                    3.1.0 | ${jetty.base}\lib\servlet-api-3.1.jar
 etc...
```

You may check this list, and find that it is missing the http-client jar (**e.g. jetty-client-9.4.0.v20161208.jar**)

Jetty can load this jar (it can be found in its lib folder), but it requires to mention it explicitly.

To do that, go to your Jetty **start.ini** file and add the relevant module:

```
module=client
```

Now, check again the list of jars loaded - the jetty-client jar is there;

The server will now start as needed.